# Node How to install a dependency in script?

Tags: node.js

I added a script in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-cleanup": "npm run playwright install [chromium]"
}
```

to install playwright which is installed as a dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "playwright": "^1.40.1",
    "playwright-chromium": "^1.39.0"
  },
```

However, I get the error that playwright isnt installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` to install the full list of dependencies?

Comment: Generally speaking you **never** edit dependencies manually in package.json. Instead you use the `npm` command. If you install playwright by running `npm install playwright@1.40.1` your package.json will be updated with the correct dependencies.

Comment: no, I MUST add the script heroku-cleanup where it installs a package because otherwise its only working in development, not when I deploy it. I am required to do this so it does work in heroku, so just running npm install in my terminal does not help